# CodeIgniter - Sanitize data using active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When i set

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE; and  $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

in application/config/config.php then the inputs are entered into the database sucessfully.But when i set them to True the database does not accept the values i.e the entries are not added into the database.Can anybody help?

controller-function:validation and loading model

```
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }
function validate(){    
        $config=array(
                       array('field'=>'First_name',
                     'label'=>'firstname',
                         'rules'=>'trim|required|htmlspecialchars'),
                  array('field'=>'Last_name',
                    'label'=>'lastname',
                        'rules'=>'trim|required'),
                 array('field'=>'Password',
                   'label'=>'password',
                   'rules'=>'trim|required'),
                 array('field'=>'Re-password',
                       'label'=>'re-password',
                            rules'=>'trim|required'),
                 array('field'=>'Email',
                     'label'=>'email',
                           'rules'=>'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]')
        ); 
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run()==False){
            echo validation_errors();       
        }   
        else{
            $this->load->model("v/register","foo");
            $p=$this->foo->registeration();  
        } 
    }
```

model class

```
class register extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    function registeration(){
                      $data=array(
                    'First_name'=>$_POST['First_name'],
                    'Last_name'=>$_POST['Last_name'],
                    'Username'=> NULL,
                    'Email'=>$_POST['Email'],
                    'Password'=>$_POST['Password']
                    ) ;
        $this->db->insert('users',$data);
    }
}
```

i am using html tags and not form_open()
i am calling controller form view using ajax.controller loads the model

Comment: this is not sufficient info to help. you are using `html <form></form> tags` or CI `form_open() and form_close()` secondly when you set both true have you tried `print_r($this->input->post())` paste output here.

Comment: How do you generate your form? Do you know how CSRF protection works?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv i have created my form using simple html.I am passing data to controller using ajax.The view page is simple html with js.

Comment: Then please post the relevant HTML and JS where you pass the CSRF token to the server.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your edits and suggestions.I worked out a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

open form with

```
echo form_open('controller/method');
```

This will generate a hidden input with a unique token. Using  will not

Also, get inputs with

```
'First_name'=>$this->input->post('First_name')
```

Don't use

```
'First_name'=>$_POST['First_name']
```